# Using login username in Spring security to make queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Hello I am trying to get the username when there is a successful login. For managing logins I use a config java class as follows:

```
@Configuration

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home",
                            "/error",
                            "/member/register",
                            "/css/**",
                            "/js/**",
                            "/fonts/**",
                            "**.html",
                            "/static/**",
                            "/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();
        http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

}
```

And I have a simple UI for login. I believe I get the login username by implementing the interface UserDetails [(documentation)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#getAuthorities--). I have to define how to getUsername() but currently I have to provide it a user instead of it giving me the current user logged in. Here is how I implemented it:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Member member;

    public UserDetailsImpl(Member member) {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public UserDetailsImpl() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>(1);
        // authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(member.getRole()));

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return member.getPassword();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return member.getUsername();
    }

}
```

The constructor that doesn't take parameters should be the current logged in user. But I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the username inside a controller after a successful login?

Comment: yea I just want to display the username in the homecontroller for now. But what I really want to do is access it in another controller so I can get Info from a table to query another table, if that makes any sense.

Comment: How you are authenticating a user for the next request after login? Inside any filter? Show that code please.

Comment: Also show the controller code where checking username and password for login is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently authenticated user in a controller you can add Pricipal as a parameter in the method signature.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public String home(Principal principal) {
    /*  
      Spring will inject the prinical for you.
      Then you can call getName() to get the username;
    */
    String user = principal.getName();  
    // do stuff with user
    return "home";
}
```

Ther are several ways to do this and this is just one.  There is a good write on other ways and benefit of each here.

http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: Thanks for the link `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  String currentUserName = authentication.getName();` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Then you can get the detail object from `authentication`, and get the login username from detail object, maybe you need to cast your own Class, more about the `SecurityContextHolder`, `Authentication` see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects)

Comment: When I do authentication.toString() I get this long string: anything.torg.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@718e0871: Principal: com.cassandrabankapp.dto.UserDetailsImpl@718d88b9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B8EBC130F41BBEB6C08E63092294063; Not granted any authorities ->I'm not sure where the login username will be defined. I tried authentication.getCredentials() but that did not return.

Comment: Based on the answer below and the fact that I got com.cassandrabankapp.dto.UserDetailsImpl@718d88b9 as my principle, do I have to type cast it with the object I pass in UserDetailsImpl.

Answer (score -2):

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Object obj = securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (obj instanceof User) {
        User springSecurityUser = (User) obj;
        String  userConnectedName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> listRole = securityContext.getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: Answers are more useful when they have an explanation about why and how they work and provide context rather than simply a vomit of code.

Comment: yes you're right, SecurityContext will store the details of authenticated user, so we can access to user name and his roles